# como reconocer un error y mostrarlo hasta pulsar intro

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un script en Python para usarlo como un menú que me facilite el testeo de otros ficheros.
mi problema ahora mismo seria que necesito una forma de que cuando haya un error se quede en pantalla hasta que pulse *intro* en vez de borrarlo rápido y volver al menú anterior.
intente con `try/except` y no me a funcionado.

me gustaría que en la zona marcada en el segundo menú que mostraré a continuación, después de iniciar ese fichero si da error que muestre el error y volver al menú anterior solo cuando pulse enter.

Si alguien sabe estaría muy agradecido en que pueda ayudarme con mi duda.
muchas gracias y buen día.

```
while not main_menu_exit:
    #mostramos el menu principal

    main_sel = main_menu.show()
    if main_sel == 0:
        os.chdir('excusaleria/')
        while not exc_menu_back:
    #mostramos menu de excusaleria(proyecto)
            exc_sel = exc_menu.show()
            if exc_sel == 0:
                os.system('clear')
                os.system('python3 excusaleria1.0.py')
                while not ej_menu_back:
                    selection = ej_menu.show()
                    if selection == 0:
                        os.system('clear')
                        os.system('python3 excusaleria1.0.py')
                        print("")
                    elif selection == 1:
                        ej_menu_back = True
                ej_menu_back = False
            elif exc_sel == 1:
                os.system("python3 excusaleria2.0.py")
                input("\nEnter para salir")
            elif exc_sel == 2:
                os.system('python3 excusaleria3.0.py')
               #-----------------aqui-------------#
            elif exc_sel == 3:
                os.chdir('../')
                exc_menu_back = True   
        exc_menu_back = False
    elif main_sel == 1:
        os.chdir('to do list/')
        os.system('python3 Todo_list.py')
        os.chdir('../')
    elif main_sel == 2:
        os.chdir('Dice Roll/')
        os.system('python3 dados.py')
        os.chdir('../')
    elif main_sel == 3:
        os.system('python3 sakalaka.py')
        input("enter para salir")
    elif main_sel == 4:
        main_menu_exit = True
```

Asi es como queda con el except

```
elif exc_sel == 2:
     try:
         os.system('python3 excusaleria3.0.py')
      except:
         input("pulsa enter para salir")
```

asi y con:

```
except Exception:
```

Comment: ponle un `input()`

Comment: @Christian ya lo intente pero entonces también tengo que pulsarlo aunq la aplicación funcione,la cosa esq cuando no funcione,muestre el error y dsps de darle a enter volver atrás.

Comment: pues mételo en el `except` asi solo se ejecuta si hay un error

Comment: tampoco sigue,sigue desapareciendo segun aparece

Comment: @Christian ya lo edite,esta al final.

Comment: Algo raro, no puedo probarlo por que estas leyendo archivos propios